# Which preposition is correct, in or at?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct, *"the metaphor is in line 23"* or *"the metaphor is at line 23"*?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, both can be correct.

They have subtly different interpretations:

- The metaphor is located **in** [*the text of*] line 23.
- The metaphor is located [*somewhere*] **at** line 23.

A different example might help:

- My friend is waiting for me **in** the grocery store.
  (She is actually inside the building.)
- My friend is waiting for me **at** the grocery store.
   (She could be standing on the sidewalk just outside, but go to the grocery store and you should find her.)

Both *in* and *at* convey a location, but *in* is more specific.

---

Of course, if the sentence in the question is talking not about a location of text on a page, but describing a metaphor that's part of the literal phrase *line 23*, then only *in* would be correct.

If that's the intention, then it would normally be styled differently:

> The metaphor is **in** "line 23."
>   The metaphor is **in** the phrase *line 23*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

'the metaphor is  line 23' or

'the metaphor is  line 23'

'At' is not appropriate.